# I have to store employee data in a ConcurrentHashMap containing name and id as key and other details as value

Tags: java, pojo, concurrenthashmap

Here I have used two ConcurrentHashMaps,

1st map: key = name
      value = Employee obj (containing 2nd map)

2nd map: key = id
      value = Employee details( pojo class)
But I m doing it wrong. pls someone explain what should be my approach.
here is my code -

```
        import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

        public class POJODemo {
            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                ConcurrentHashMap <String, Employee> outer_concurrentHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Employee>();
                Employee empobj = new Employee();
                empobj.setId("123");
                outer_concurrentHashMap.put("disha", empobj.toString());
                System.out.println(outer_concurrentHashMap);
            }
        }

        class Employee
        {
            public static ConcurrentHashMap <String , POJODetails> inner_concurrentHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap <String , POJODetails>();

            private String id;

            public String getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public void setId(String id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            POJODetails details = new POJODetails("korba", 12345);
        }

        class POJODetails{

            public POJODetails(String address, int phone) {
                super();
                this.address = address;
                this.phone = phone;
            }

            private String address;
            private int phone;

            public String getAddress() {
                return address;
            }
            public void setAddress(String address) {
                this.address = address;
            }
            public int getPhone() {
                return phone;
            }
            public void setPhone(int phone) {
                this.phone = phone;
            }

            public String toString()
            {
                return ;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by you're doing it wrong? Which error are you receiving?

Comment: Why are you using .toString()?
outer_concurrentHashMap.put("disha", empobj.toString());

Answer (score 0):

'outer_concurrentHashMap.put("disha", empobj.toString());' is incorrect; should be 'outer_concurrentHashMap.put("disha", empobj);'

You cannot convert your object to a string and put it in a hash map that only takes employee as a value. When you print the Map it will call.toString on the employee and still print it visibly for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you created your HashMap, you specified that it would take an object of type **String** as a '**key**' and an object of type **Employee** as a '**value**'.

Using HashMap.get('key'), will return an object of type Employee, which is the mapped value to your key. So you could write:

```
Employee retrievedEmployee = outer_concurrentHashMap.get("disha");
//'retrievedEmployee' has the same value as 'empobj'
```

In your code, when you write:

```
outer_concurrentHashMap.put("disha", empobj.toString());
```

you are not adding an object of type Employee to your hashmap, but the representation of **that** object as a string.

The correct code would be:

```
outer_concurrentHashMap.put("disha", empobj);
```